# Add labels and title to a plot derived from an lapply function

Tags: r, plot, cross-correlation

I can't figure out how to add title and axis labels for this whole figure. (not just axis labels on each panel)

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16709, 15126, 14883, 16587, 
15095, 15492, 14549, 17410, 16314, 17348, 14761, 14457, 16375, 
17014, 15857, 17836, 15826, 15522, 15918, 15857), class = "Date"), 
    Commonname = c("Black Sea Bass", "Pinfish", "Silver Perch", 
    "Black Sea Bass", "Silver Perch", "Pinfish", "Pinfish", "Pigfish", 
    "Pinfish", "Black Sea Bass", "Silver Perch", "Pinfish", "Black Sea Bass", 
    "Pigfish", "Black Sea Bass", "Pinfish", "Black Sea Bass", 
    "Pigfish", "Black Sea Bass", "Silver Perch"), CPUE = c(1.07628582778677, 
    7.86657009496217, 1.85135216165977, 0.348590691952807, 0.397594400562561, 
    4.49617260026057, 9.8560683819882, 2.52182932296262, 4.66061566304416, 
    1.85247646459195, 1.09432152065719, 12.0038255707299, 0.145989032254548, 
    1.86725301741492, 1.07356515883229, 11.5172014403701, 0.296643539261688, 
    2.70394855189782, 1.14838123183663, 0.871334772441085), Discharge = c(3.02423424, 
    0.232938467873684, 2.141316416, 1.31224770666667, 1.03639488, 
    14.38635024, 1.2352637664, 8.27794453333333, 7.04587330461538, 
    6.47180464, 5.84804846222222, 2.37460535832896, 1.68201792, 
    19.73397792, 3.56857026461538, 4.89821025684211, 5.41174500571429, 
    33.25524992, 47.1935879314286, 3.88199730666667)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
df.split <- split(df, df$Commonname, drop = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(seq_along(df.split), function(x) ccf(df.split[[x]]$CPUE,df.split[[x]]$Discharge, lag.max = 5,
                                              ylab = "", xlab = "", main= names(df.split)[x]))
```

[image]

I can't add it into the function or it applies to all panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added `title()` function;

```
df.split <- split(df, df$Commonname, drop = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(seq_along(df.split), function(x) ccf(df.split[[x]]$CPUE,df.split[[x]]$Discharge, lag.max = 5,
                                              ylab = "", xlab = "", main= names(df.split)[x]))
title("This is a main title", line = -1, outer = TRUE,xlab = 'This is x axis',ylab = 'This is y axis')
```

[image]

Comment: Weird, I tried that right before i posted the question.  Any idea about how to increase the margins to allow more room for title?

Comment: you can pass `mar` argument into `par`. like `par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(5,5,5,5))`, it sets 5 units margin for each side.

Comment: par(mfrow = c(2, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0)) then title('Main', line = 1, outer = TRUE) creates some outer margin at the top and puts the title in that space

Answer (score 0):

I got it to where I need for the actual plot and data using this code and with the help of the previous answers.

```
d.select.ccf <- BD %>% 
  group_by(Zone, Date, Commonname) %>%
  filter(Zone == "D") %>% 
  summarise(Number = sum(Number), CPUE = mean((CPUE)), Discharge = mean (Discharge)) %>% 
  ungroup()

d.spp <- subset(d.select.ccf,  Commonname == "Pigfish" | Commonname == "Pinfish"
                | Commonname == "Silver Perch"
                | Commonname == 'Spottail Pinfish' | Commonname == "Dusky Pipefish"
                | Commonname == "Black Sea Bass"
                | Commonname == "Pink Shrimp" | Commonname == "Scallops"
                | Commonname == 'Grass Porgy' | Commonname == 'Lane Snapper'
                | Commonname == 'White Grunt'| Commonname == "Spotted Seatrout")
d.split <- split(d.spp, d.spp$Commonname, drop = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(4,3),omi=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2), mai=c(0.55,0.6,0.7,0.5))
d.ccf.plot <- lapply(seq_along(d.split), function(x) ccf(d.split[[x]]$CPUE,d.split[[x]]$Discharge, lag.max = 5,
                                                         xlab = "", ylab = "", sub = "", main= names(d.split)[x]))
title("Steinhatchee Lag Correlations", sub = " ", line = -1, outer = TRUE,
      xlab = 'Lag (months)',ylab = 'Correlation Coefficient', cex.main = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.5)
```

Of course you would need the full data set to achieve this image which is way too large to post here. But I hope this alternate method can help someone.

[image]